# How do I find out what items are less purchased in the store؟

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

We have two table , the  first  is

```
products (pro_id,pro_name,supleir_id,quantity,unit,price,enter_date)
```

the second table is

```
 customers(cus_id,cus_name,purchased_item,pro_id,quantity,total_price,date,invoice)
```

We want to create a procedure using PLSQL to know which products are less purchased by customers

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: **Why is your database not normalized?** What happens if the same `cus_id` wants to purchase multiple different products on different dates? Is `cus_id` the primary-key of `customers` or not?

Comment: What do you mean by (rephrased) "purchased less"? That sounds like you want to do a time-series comparison - but you haven't said what the criteria are or the business rules for performing the comparison...

Comment: Take a look at the following link [Oracle / PLSQL: Procedures](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/procedures.php)

Comment: I want to know which products are not sold much in the store
, and for the subject of cus_id Yes, it is a primary-key, but we have another table that contains customer purchases with dates that I did not ask in the text of the question,
So, the main idea is that I want to write a PLSQL code that show me the items that were not sold in the store or sold a small amount
thank you sir

Comment: @AnkitBajpai ....

Comment: Please read and heed https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I think "less purchased" means the product id with the lowest occurrences. However, that is still ambiguous whether it means lowest number of times purchased (count of pro_id) or lowest number of items sold (sum of quantity) from customers.  
Either way one method would to rank the target value and then select only the the rows with the lowest ranking. It creates a Subquery Factoring (more commonly known as CTE) to rank the product from the Customers table by quantity. It then Joins the result with the Product table. ( See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=899e34eafae8a5e37db6cfb39d75d6b3) )

```
with less_purchased(pro_id, number_purchased) as 
     ( select pro_id, cnt
         from (-- rank each product by quantity  
               select pro_id, cnt,  dense_rank() over( order by cnt desc) rnk
                from  (-- get sum of quantity for each product
                       select pro_id, sum(quantity) cnt 
                         from customers
                         group by pro_id
                       ) sum_query
              ) rank_query
        -- discard all but rank 1 
        where rnk = 1
     )
-- get product information and quantity purchased
select p.*, lp.number_purchased
  from products  p 
  join less_purchased lp on (lp.pro_id = p.pro_id);
```

The above may produce output with multiple product rows as products with the same quantity will have the same rank.  
To get same for number of times purchased replace *sum(quantity)* with *count(*)* and remove *desc* or order by.